# CGContextAddEllipseInRect does not draw anything

Tags: objective-c

I´m trying to draw a circle with a number inside of it:

```
   -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    //Drawing code
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rect);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

    // Label and index code
    UILabel* circleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    NSString *i=[Index stringValue];
    [circleLabel setText:i];
    [self addSubview:circleLabel];




}
```

I call the drawRect method from my own method:

```
-(void)addPhotoIndex:(NSNumber*)tempNumber withCoordinate:(NSString*)currentTouchPos{
    self.coord= CGPointFromString(currentTouchPos);
    CGRect rect= CGRectMake ((coord.x - 5), (coord.y- 5), 5, 5);
    NSNumber *Index= tempNumber;
    [self drawRect:rect];




}
```

That it is itself called from the ViewController.

But this is not drawing nothing, nor giving any errors. Can somebody help me please?

SOLUTION:

At the end, this is what it worked:

```
  -(void)addPhotoIndex:(NSNumber*)tempNumber withCoordinate:(NSString*)currentTouchPos{

    self.coord= CGPointFromString(currentTouchPos);
    CGRect rect= CGRectMake ((coord.x - 3), (coord.y- 3), 3, 3);
    NSNumber *Index= tempNumber;
    NSString *i=[Index stringValue];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];

    // Drawing Point
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
    [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rect);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
    [ i drawAtPoint:self.coord withFont:font];
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


}
```

A point with the index number are drawn next to each other in the correct position :) Thanks for your useful help!

Comment: I got the console message: Invalid Context 0x0. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Do you call the method from anywhere yourself?

Comment: Yes, I call it from my method:

Comment: -(void)addPhotoIndex:(NSNumber*)tempNumber withCoordinate:(NSString*)currentTouchPos{
    self.coord= CGPointFromString(currentTouchPos);
    CGRect rect= CGRectMake ((coord.x - 5), (coord.y- 5), 5, 5);
    NSNumber *Index= tempNumber;
    [self drawRect:rect];
      
}

Comment: You're not supposed to call this method yourself, it gets called automatically by the system and it takes care of setting up an appropriate graphics context. If you need your view to be redrawn, call `[self setNeedsDisplay];`

Comment: OK, but I need the view to draw a circle in a point after something happens in the controller, not when the view is loaded...

Comment: Did you read my comment till the end? Call `setNeedsDisplay` when "something happens". And how about reading the [UIView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)? It's all there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you should be using is `drawRect:` not `drawInRect:`.

You also do not need to create your own context as this is set up for you in `drawRect:`

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
{
  // UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size); <-- not needed
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
  CGContextBeginPath(context);
  CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rect);
  CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke); // Or kCGPathFill

  /*
   * As @Jonathan Cichon points out you should not add subview's here
   * either add them elsewhere or draw the string manually
   */
  // UILabel* circleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
  // NSString *i=[Index stringValue];
  // [circleLabel setText:i];
  // [self addSubview:circleLabel];
  // UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); <-- not needed
}
```

Comment: But if I don´t insert the UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(), then I become the error that the context is invalid 0x0.

Comment: Did you change the name of the method?

Comment: No, the method is 
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    //Drawing code
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rect);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

    
    
}

Comment: Can you update your original question with the exact code you have

Answer (score 1):

I assume you implementated `- (void)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect` in a subclass of `UIView`. If so use `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`, so the context for drawing is already allocated when your method is called. Remove the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` and `UIGraphicsEndImageContext` calles. Also you should not add a subview in `drawRect`, use `[i drawInRect:withFont:]` instead

Comment: Yes, I implemented it in a View. Maybe I should explain what I´m trying. First I have a View. When the user touches 2 times then an actionsheet comes up and two options appear: take a photo or choose a photo. When the user has already chosen a foto then I want to draw a circle in the coordinates of the touch with the foto number...